# Send unassigned JSON properties to server when using stringify i.e. retain properties name whether property value is empty/null

Tags: json, angular, stringify

I have two model properties:

```
ng-model="category.name"    mandatory field
ng-model="category.desc"    optional
```

This is how I am sending data to the server (ASP.net)

```
var rdt = "{'dt':" + JSON.stringify($scope.category) + "}";
```

However, if an optional property has an unassigned value, the property name is not found server side and gives an error. Are there any ways to retain unassigned properties of JSON?

Comment: Seems like if the server is crashing when optional properties aren't present, that's a problem in the server's code, not the stringify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several solutions:

- ## Solution 1: Initialize the variables in your scope for example:

```
$scope.category.desc = null
```

- ## Solution 2: Create a function to take care of that

```
function ToJson(object, properties) {
   var result = {};
   for(var i = 0; i < properties.lenght; i++) {
      var property = properties[i];
      if(!object[property]) {
         result[property] = null;
      } else {
         result[property] = object[property];
      }      
   }

  return JSON.stringify(result);
}

// And then use it like this:
var rdt = "{'dt':" + ToJson($scope.category, ["name", "desc"]) + "}";
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for replying.I tried first one, but still not working. Second solution is working